# SwiftUI: edit List inside of a Section

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

Without `Form` and `Section`, I can edit a list:

```
var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(modeConfigurations.sorted, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text("\(item.defaultSortIndex)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                   EditButton()
            )
} // Body
```

[image]

I'd like to edit inside a `Section` of a `Form`, but it doesn't work there:

```
var body: some View {
    Form{
        Section(header: Text("Sort")){
            List {
                ForEach(modeConfigurations.sorted, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text("\(item.defaultSortIndex)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                   EditButton()
            )
        } // Sort Section
    } // Form
} // Body
```

I can't edit and the `Text` inside `ForEach` is not rendered as separate line.

[image]

How can I edit a `List` inside a `Section` of a `Form`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put `.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())` on the `Form` instead to make it work.

Also `List` is not needed as `Section` already "acts like" a `List`. (Thanks to @Sweeper for mentioning that)

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section(header: Text("Sort")) {
            // List { // <- This is not needed as Section contains an implicit list.
                ForEach(modeConfigurations.sorted, id: \.id) { item in
                    Text("\(item.defaultSortIndex)")
                }
                .onMove(perform: move)
            // } // <- Removeed this as we removed `List`
        } // Sort Section
    } // Form
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton()) // <- Misplacing this was the issue.
} // Body
```

Comment: I don't think you need the `List` either. The `Section` already "acts like" a `List`.

Comment: I was aware to change the original code. But as you mentioned, I decided to add it to the answer. Thanks @Sweeper